# Dojo private modules use them?

Tags: dojo, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need help with ArcGIS API for JavaScript, I need to use private modules in code for my tools, but I can't figure out how use them in my app like on click launch this module.

I'm lost in DoJo...

The map.js:

```
     /**
 * This file contain :
   * - Map init
   * - Principal layers to add
   * - Reference to the tools files
   * - Style of the principal page (map, navbar...
  **/

require({
    packages: [{ name: "src", location: "/src", type: "text/javascript" }]
},[
"esri/map", 
"esri/toolbars/draw",
"esri/graphic",
"dojo/parser",
"esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

"dijit/registry",
"esri/geometry/Geometry",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
"dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
"dijit/form/Button", 
"dijit/WidgetSet",
"src/modules/zoningSelection",
"dojo/domReady!"], 
function(Map, Draw, Graphic, parser, registry, dijit, zoningSelection){
   parser.parse();

   map = new Map(map,{
      basemap:"hybrid",
      center:[-1.486075,46.199997],
      zoom:15
   });
   console.log(map);
    var selectionTool = dijit.byId("select");
    selectionTool.on("click",startSelect);

    var validationTool = dijit.byId("end");
    validationTool.on("click", endSelect);

    var deleteTool = dijit.byId("del");
    deleteTool.on("click", delSelect);


   function startSelect(){

        var select = new zoningSelection(map, Draw.POLYGON);
        console.log(select);
    };

    function endSelect (){
        alert("Validé");
    }
    function delSelect(){
        alert("Suppr");
    }
});
```

My Module to load in the first code:

```
require(["esri/map", 
    "esri/toolbars/draw",
    "esri/graphic",

    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

    "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/graphicsUtils",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/geometry/Geometry",
    "esri/dijit/Popup",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
    "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/WidgetSet", 
    //"dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/domReady!"],function (map, drawType, Draw, GraphicsLayer, Graphic, SimpleFillSymbol, graphicsUtils, dijit) {
        console.log("séléction lancée ou non ");
        console.log(map);
        console.log(drawType);
    var _drawTool = new Draw(map);
    var _drawingLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    console.log(_drawingLayer);

    map.addLayer(_drawingLayer);

    _drawTool.setRespectDrawingVertexOrder(true);
    _drawTool.on("draw-complete", _onDrawComplete);

    activate(drawType);
    //map.disableMapNavigation();

    var _onDrawComplete = function(evt) {
        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        map.enableMapNavigation();

        var geom = evt.geometry;
        //create object from geometry and symbol
        var graphic = new Graphic(geom, symbol);        
        _drawingLayer.add(graphic);

        var points = graphicsUtils.getGeometries(_drawingLayer.graphics)[0].rings[0];

        require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array){
            array.forEach(points, function(point, i){
                console.log("point #" + i + " : x=" + point[0] + ", y=" + point[1]);
            });
        });
    };
});
```

How can I use them together?

Answer (score 1):

I fix my problems by hours on the dojo docs i try this solution before but without thinking of variable order in function here is the corrected code fort the module

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/toolbars/draw",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/graphicsUtils",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/geometry/Geometry",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    //"src/map.js",
    "dojo/domReady!"],function (declare, Map, Draw, Graphic, SimpleFillSymbol, GraphicsLayer,
        GraphicsUtils, Polygon, Geometry, array) {
        var _drawTool;
        var _drawingLayer;
        var _map;

        return declare(null, {

            constructor: function(map){
                _map = map;
                _drawTool = new Draw(_map);
                _drawingLayer = new GraphicsLayer();                    
                _map.addLayer(_drawingLayer);

                _drawTool.setRespectDrawingVertexOrder(true);                   

                var _onDrawComplete = function(evt) {
                    var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();

                    var geom = evt.geometry;
                    //create object from geometry and symbol
                    var graphic = new Graphic(geom, symbol);        
                    _drawingLayer.add(graphic);
                };

                _drawTool.on("draw-complete", _onDrawComplete);
            },

            activate: function(drawType) {
                _drawTool.activate(drawType);
                //_map.disableMapNavigation();
            },

            deactivate: function() {
                _drawTool.deactivate();
                //_map.enableMapNavigation();
            },

            getGeometry: function() {
                return GraphicsUtils.getGeometries(_drawingLayer.graphics);
            },

            getSelectedPolygons: function() {
                var polygons = new Array();

                array.forEach(GraphicsUtils.getGeometries(_drawingLayer.graphics),
                    function(graphic){
                        var polygon = new Array();
                        array.forEach(polygon.rings[0],
                            function(point) {
                            polygon.push(point);
                        });

                        polygons.push(polygon);
                });

                /*var points = GraphicsUtils.getGeometries(_drawingLayer.graphics)[0].rings[0];

                require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array){
                    array.forEach(points, function(point, i){
                        console.log("point #" + i + " : x=" + point[0] + ", y=" + point[1]);
                    });
                });*/
            }
```

});
});